# NativeScript. Display barcode and qr

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I'm using `nativescript-barcodescanner` for scanning codes, but cannot find any solution for displaying this barcode on screen.

Comment: Hi, have same issue have you found solution for this?

Comment: @LyubomirVelchev Try default js scripts like this. http://lindell.me/JsBarcode/

Answer (score 0):

Correct, that plugin is for scanning, not for displaying.

There are many services that can transform text into a barcode. The Google Chart API for instance. Just try adding an image to your view with this as src: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=1234567890

Comment: Tnx, but i need something like this https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode.

Comment: Did you try that library in NativeScript?

Comment: Yes. But it uses `document.querySelector` and it does not work

Comment: OK, makes sense, perhaps a different node-based lib then. But what's the problem with using online services?

Comment: Need offline mode

Comment: I knew you were gonna say that :)  Most times my users need to create a barcode they have access to the internet (2G is fine for this, that barcode I linked to is about 1KB). But yeah if that's still insufficient you'll have to continue your search for a JS lib that doesn't depend on the DOM. Did you encounter native SDK's that support what you need by the way?

Comment: No. I did not. I'm trying nativescript only 3-rd day )

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install a font, then use it like you would any other font. For example, if you want to display text in Code 39, you can download a [free Code 39 font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Libre+Barcode+39), add a Label to your page, and add a class to the Label with your font family set for the font.

Here's an example

```html
<Label text="Sample Text" class="code-39" />
```

In your css add

```css
.code-39 {
  font-family: 'Libre Barcode 39', 'LibreBarcode39-Regular';
}
```